# Is it safe to cover a floor lamp with an Aluminium metal pie plate?

Tags: safety

Please see the image below. I'm trying to convert my IKEA NYFORS floor lamp into a reading light, by covering the top with an Aluminium pie plate.

Will this be a fire or electrical hazard? Does anyone foresee any dangers or risks?

As I have 3 of these floor lamps in my attic, I don't want to waste money buying a reading light. I'm unemployed because of COVID.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a tendency to retain as much of the original structure as possible when optimizing the performance of a piece of equipment, so as to be able to return it to its original state. The pie plate could help, as long as it does not hinder convection cooling of the fluorescent bulb (you could feel it after some minutes; leave more air space if necessary).

However, since you have three of these floor lamps, perhaps you would consider modifying one more severely. The light escaping the top of the lampshade is maybe a sixth of the output; what comes out the bottom of the shade is maybe a third - but half of this is directed away from your book, so you get only a sixth plus maybe half of the light reflected from the top, so an extra twelfth, for a quarter overall.

If you tilt the shade, aim it down a little, perhaps be a little artistic, you could make an unconventional lighting improvement that suits your purpose even better. Aluminum foil inside the shade will help protect the shade and reflect more light in the desired direction. Just be sure to allow hot air to rise above the bulb.

[image]

Of course, the shade needs to be surgically modified and will never be the same, but if it's in the attic now, it's not being used anyway. Work with the worst of the three shades - and you can always get a new shade, if you need one.

If you're comfortable with modifying the shade, I think your lamp has an adjustable height setting. Lower the shade to the height of your head in whatever chair you are using. Then cut a *large* window in the lamp shade, and place some aluminum foil on the other side of the shade to reflect more of the light toward you. Most lamp shade harps have a tiltable setting, so you could aim the window more toward your book. If you are careful and plan ahead, you can probably make the modifications essentially reversible, although some "scars" on the shade will persist. But you could turn them around to the back.

Comment: Thanks. I don't understand your pictures though. You rotated the shade 90° counterclockwise? But you wrote "If you tilt the shade, aim it down a little"?

Comment: @Rabah Y.: Well, the picture is just cut and pasted. Basically, it's a way to aim the light (also suggested by HRM below). And I agree that the pan probably does not reflect much. However, a way to "tunnel" the light, i.e., aim it more, would be to line the shade with aluminum foil in addition to tilting it. And use aluminum foil instead of a pie pan.         I also added a couple lines to my original answer.

Comment: Thanks. Is it safe to use aluminum foil so close to a light bulb? Can you please elaborate on this in your answer?

Comment: Sometimes you might wonder if it is safe to have lightshade material so close to a light bulb. Then you realize that it doesn't absorb much energy (not very dark colored) and is well ventilated. Aluminum foil in the same place would absorb much less energy (reflective - and you can't really set aluminum foil on fire), so it should be safe. It will not be near exposed electrical connections, so OK there. Keep in mind that ventilation is good - do not make a reflective bucket, where the air will stagnate, heat up and diminish the life of the fluorescent bulb by overheating it.

Answer (score 2):

#### TL;DR Play it safe, test carefully and seriously consider switching to LED to cut the risk (and the energy cost).

**Any light source can catch fire.** That being said, if a device was originally *designed* and tested for use with incandescent bulbs and is now being used with fluorescent bulbs then the total heat is much less, and therefore the risk is minimal.

A *typical* rating for a lamp like this is 75W, but sometimes 100W and sometimes even 150W (based on a traditional 3-way bulb at 50W/100W/150W). *See if you can find a rating somewhere on the lamp, typically on or near the socket.*

The likely minimum maximum (that sounds funny, but it fits here), *provided it was originally designed for incandescent bulbs*, is 60W. **Almost all the power that goes into a light bulb, no matter what the technology, ends up turned into heat.** Consider the following:

- 60W incandescent = 100% (at most) of original design rating
- 13W compact fluorescent = 22%
- 6W LED = 10%

Plus a typical LED bulb has almost all the heat in the base, so that's something on the order of 5W coming out the bottom (on or near the socket) and 1W out the top. So the amount of heat that needs to dissipated via the top is **much** less than with an incandescent bulb, and the overall heat is 1/2 that of a fluorescent bulb.

Of all the materials to use on top, aluminum is one of the best. That's because aluminum is a [great conductor](https://www.classical-music.com/features/artists/20-greatest-conductors-all-time/) of heat (and electricity too, but that's not directly relevant to this question). So whatever heat does get up to the aluminum pan will conduct and dissipate quickly.

Answer (score 2):

### Pie tins don't reflect.  They mostly get warm.

What that means is the light hitting the pie tin will be a write-off.  **It's a shade, not a reflector**.

Well, not quite entirely - if they didn't reflect *at all* they'd look like a black hole.  So you're getting *something*.  But light is exponential (it's a decibel scale) which means, what looks like "a fair bit" isn't much at all. To get good reflectivity it needs to be polished to a mirror finish.  Or be painted a high-albedo white; my top white paint is 91% albedo.  Difference being, paint will diffuse (scatter) the light; mirror will return it coherent (aimed the way it arrived).

The upshot is, don't expect your "reflector" to make the existing light any brighter.

### Aiming beats reflecting any day of the week

The real win when you want focused (reading) lights, is a light which is *aimed where you want it*.

The fact is, since Edison, all technologies of light have emitted a *sphere* of light.  We don't want a sphere - *we never, ever wanted a sphere* - but we've been stuck with it so long we got used to it (Stockholm Syndrome). What we really want - almost always - is a cone or wedge of light.  Enter LEDs, which do emit a wedge of light of about 160 degrees.  *Enough to redirect with lenses*.  Lenses unlike reflectors are very efficient.  So you should eventually change to a reading light with a PAR type "bulb" intended to cast a beam of the shape you want, using LED tech with lenses.

Answer (score 1):

Since the bulb you'll be using produces little heat, it's not going to set on fire, or melt. I'd be inclined to try it out without fixing permanently, and feel after every 10 minutes or so. If it does (unlikely) get too warm, several smallish holes drilled will solve that. And, of course, there will be an air gap between the top of the shade and the aluminium - won't there?

Electrically, if it's fixed to the metal of the shade, it will be good, as that ought to already be earthed.

Comment: "And, of course, there will be an air gap between the top of the shade and the aluminium - won't there?" Yes. You're correct. Don't hesitate to edit your post, to remove this question mark and uncertainty.

Comment: @JimStewart - more than a few times on this site I've commented that the geographical locaton of OP is a relevant and often important factor. Here's another example. With 'aluminum' spelled three different ways, there wasn't even a bit of a clue!

Comment: Most table or floor lamps in the US are not earthed. Standard US lampcord is two wire. It is polarized so the hot conductor is a small pin recessed into the center of the socket, but there is a possibility that the metal base and vertical shaft of a floor lamp could become hot. I am surprised we allow this, but the risk in practice must be miniscule because I never see reports of shock or electrocution from lamps.